# PHP PCRE regex compilation error

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

When I attempt the following:

```
$searchText = preg_quote($searchText, '/');
$remarks = preg_replace('/'.$searchText.'/i', '<span class="searchText">$0</span>', $remarks);
```

I get the following error message:

> Regular expression too large at offset 0

I haven't got a clue what this means, why I'm getting it or how to fix it. 
When I google this error message I get references to php.ini settings that I can't even find.

Comment: 'too large' is a pretty explicit message and a common phrase in contemporary language - are you _sure_ you 'haven't got a clue'?

Comment: Apparently your regex is too large.  Without seeing what that regex is, we can't help you.

Comment: I don't understand why my regex would be too large. The lines above are in a loop that processes a single DB record at a time. $searchText is small, user entered text of maybe a dozen or so characters at most. $remarks is from a VARCHAR2(4000) field so I don't see how it's exceeding 65,000 unless something needs to be set each time through the loop. $remarks does NOT concatenate each time through the loop.

Comment: I should also mention that the problem started when I added the preg_quote() line. I added that because some users were entering the forward slash character as a part of the search string which was causing problems. I understand preg_quote() escapes any regex special characters but I don't see how it could expand something that is at most 4000 characters to over 65,000.

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression size limit is 65539 (yes, not 65536). You are exceeding the limit.

See here: http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt

```
SIZE AND OTHER LIMITATIONS

       There  are some size limitations in PCRE but it is hoped that they will
       never in practice be relevant.

       The maximum length of a compiled pattern is 65539 (sic) bytes  if  PCRE
       is compiled with the default internal linkage size of 2. If you want to
       process regular expressions that are truly enormous,  you  can  compile
       PCRE  with  an  internal linkage size of 3 or 4 (see the README file in
       the source distribution and the pcrebuild documentation  for  details).
       In  these  cases the limit is substantially larger.  However, the speed
       of execution is slower.
```

Comment: For me, the sentence "but it is hoped that they will never in practice be relevant" translates into "hitting this limit means you're doing something wrong"

Answer (score 1):

From previous questions it looks like you're trying to highlight a word that a user searches for. If so, you don't need a regex to do that, you can do this:

```
$remarks = str_replace( $searchText, '<span class="searchText">' . $searchText . '</span>', $remarks);
```

Note that it will highlight strings within words. If you want to match the whole word only I can update my answer.

Comment: The reason I did preg_replace() is because I want the replace to be case-insensitive without altering the case of the text that's displayed. I could change your str_replace() to str_ireplace(), matching and highlighting the text regardless of which case the user enters as such text, but the case of the results returned to the user are then whatever case the user entered.